# PHP, image from FTP to BLOB

Tags: php, ftp, blob

I have an image on my FTP, here : `/home/www/myImage.jpg`

I need, in PHP, to retrieve this image and create a BLOB.

I use CURL and i don't know how do to that.

I have try this :

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "ftp://MY_IP/home/www/myImage.jpg");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "LOGIN:PASSWORD");

$myBlobImage= curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

But with this, i retrieve nothing... Any ideas ? Thanks !

Comment: where do you run this code? is it on the same server with image?

Comment: Yes, same server, i run this script from /home/www/

Comment: well, you don't need CURL to read files from your own servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You are running the code on the same server as the file is stored at, then You simply could do:

```
file_get_contents('PATH/TO/MyFile.Ext');
```

which loads the file's content. Now You could easily store it to the database to a BLOB column. You could `base64_encode` the data first or instead of `file_get_contents` use a *byte stream* to read stream of bytes...